# Getting the count of multiple records in a data set

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset in a excel file. One record (row) consist of multiple variables including the "Type" parameter. In my dataset there is approx. 63000 rows. I have filtered unique records based on the column "Type" (which is approx. 600 rows). Now I would like to know the count of each "Type" in the original table. Original table is (sheet1), filtered table is (sheet2). I tried to use COUNTIF function, but this way I have to put the COUNTIF function separately for each "Type" which means 600 times. Is there a more effective way to do this?
Many thanx

TABLE EXAMPLE:

```
ID ----- TIME ----- LOCATION ----- TYPE

01 ----- 13:20:45 ----- X1 ----- A

02 ----- 14:25:15 ----- X2 ----- B

03 ----- 15:40:50 ----- X1 ----- A
```

Now I would like to know how to find out that in my table, there is 2xA, 1xB, assuming, I have 600 "Types" and a table of 60000 rows total.

Comment: How did you filter your table? And describe with example your two tables. It's unclear from your question.

Comment: @bzimor I wave edited my question a little. It would be great if you can look at ti one more time. Thank you

Comment: Did you try a pivot table?

Comment: Since you already filtered unique values in second sheet so you can apply countif formula for finding duplicate values something like this  =COUNTIF(Sheet1!D$1:D$60000,Sheet2!D1) and just drag the formula for all the rows